# How to split string using batch script?

Tags: batch-file

I am new new to batch scripting. 
Need some help to extract `string value` from the below string:

```
value=string_value (character)
```

Required Output: `string_value`

Comment: There are different ways to do it that depend on the actual format of the `text`.

Comment: For example Matt's solution would have failed if your `string_value` contained a space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
for /f "tokens=2 delims== " %%a in ("value=string_value (character)") do echo %%a
```