# win cmd batch script straightforward split string (8280a263dd758fdaf8a21f1a2d0936ff *App 1.0.exe)

Tags: batch-file

The following string is in `somefile.txt`:

`"8280a263dd758fdaf8a21f1a2d0936ff *File 1.0.exe"`

I would like to split it into 2 files, `md5sum.txt` and `app.txt`. The `md5sum.txt` should contain `"8280a263dd758fdaf8a21f1a2d0936ff"` and the `app.txt` should contain `"File 1.0.exe"`.

What's the most straightforward win cmd batch script to do that?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to split string using batch script?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22117358/how-to-split-string-using-batch-script)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@echo off
for /f "tokens=1* delims=* " %%A in (somefile.txt) do (
  >md5sum.txt set /p "=%%A"
  >app.txt    set /p "=%%B"
) <nul
```

***Edit in response to additional requirement in comment***

If it is OK to store ".exe" instead of "exe" within apptype.txt, then

```
@echo off
for /f "tokens=1* delims=* " %%A in (somefile.txt) do (
  >md5sum.txt  set /p "=%%A"
  >appname.txt set /p "=%%~nB"
  >appType.txt set /p "=%%~xB"
) <nul
```

If you must remove the leading dot, then

```
@echo off
for /f "tokens=1* delims=* " %%A in (somefile.txt) do (
  >md5sum.txt  set /p "=%%A"
  >appname.txt set /p "=%%~nB"
  set "apptype=%%~xB"
) <nul 
>apptype.txt set /p "%%apptype:~1%%"
```

Comment: Thanks @dbenham! But I need a little bit more. The ideia is to use that 2 files as input in a LaTeX document. So it's important to have exactly "8280a263dd758fdaf8a21f1a2d0936ff" and "File 1.0.exe" in each file.

Comment: It's important not to have spaces and/or new lines after the desired string.

Comment: @oqrxke - Don't forget to accept an answer if it fully answers your question to your satisfaction. You accept by clicking the check mark near the upper left corner of the answer. That action lets others know the question has been answered, it awards you 2 rep points, and awards the answer poster 15 rep points. Only 1 answer can be accepted for any one question.

Comment: I would like to add one more level of sofisticaion, split it in three parts. Maintain the md5sum.txt as it is. But split the app.txt into another 2 files, appname.txt and apptype.txt. The appname.txt should contain "File 1.0", the file name without the extension. And apptype.txt should contain "exe", only the extension.